# Aplicativo android integrado com site html com banco de dados database

Tags: android, banco-de-dados, firebase

Preciso de ajuda em uma questão.

Meu TCC consiste em um aplicativo didático, que recebe todo seu conteúdo (Textos e imagens) através de um site HTML. É possível tudo isso funcionar através do banco de dados FIREBASE? E se for possível, como e por onde eu devo começar os meus estudos para fazer isso funcionar?

Comment: É possível sim. Mas você precisa de ter conhecimentos sobre JavaScript. Se você já tem, ou quando tiver, veja como começar com o banco de dados do Firebase [aqui](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start?hl=pt-br).. E você guardaria as imagens no [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/start?hl=pt-br).

Comment: Muito obrigado!